# HTML Conflitos em dois arquivos javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com dificuldade em chamar dois arquivos *.js* em minha pagina html, porque os dois não funcionam juntos, somente separados, acredito que é um problema de conflito, quedo adicionar um efeito de *alert* personalizado no meu site, mas quando colo o código no site o *captcha* não funciona, fica carregando infinitamente deste jeito:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue abaixo o caminho dos arquivos .js que estão conflitando:

Quero adicionar o código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Excluir pedido?"></div>

<button id="btn" onclick="confirmar();">Clica</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function funcao_b() {
  alert('funcao B');
}
function confirmar() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Excluir pedido": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          funcao_b();
        },
        'Cancelar': function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          console.log('cancelado');
        }
      }
    });
}
    </script>
</html>
```

No código fonte deste site:

http://natupote.net16.net/

Como elimino este conflito?

Comment: acabei de testar e aparecu o captcha normal, se o problema era somente esse sugiro investigar melhor o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira Eu abri agora e o captcha nao funciona

Comment: pode ver novamente? estava atualizando o site constantemente neste tempo, acho q eu tinha tirado o script q dava o conflito

Comment: usa as ferramentas de debug do seu navegador e ve se tem algum erro, erro de javascript ou erro na rede, como o captch normalmente vem de fora pode ser que tenha algo errado

Comment: @NeuberOliveira, vc tinha razao, estava funcionando, me desculpe mas agora eu adicionei o script e o conflito voltou, pode atalizar a pagina q o captcha nao funcionara

Comment: obrigado pela paciencia

Comment: @NeuberOliveira acredito q o erro seja de conflito mesmo, pq o captcha pifou agora q coloquei o script da mensagem

Comment: A duvida ainda continua aberta...

Comment: isso não é conflito porque os arquivos são totalmente diferentes, um é jquery-1.12.4.js e o outro é  jquery-ui.js interface de usuário

Comment: e esta funcionado normal.

Comment: Porque você não tenta baixa os arquivos e joga em uma pasta local.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 Estranho, no meu notebook a parte do captcha nao carrega, tentei no meu celular e o erro continua, a parte do captcha nao carrega, eu ja baixei os arquivos .html no meu pc e o erro continua, o site funciona, somente a parte do captcha q trava...

Comment: @NeuberOliveira vc resolveu meu problema em 40min o q eu levei um dia tentando, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta dando um erro que o jquery nao foi inicializado, e vi que voce esta usando tambem o prototype.forms.js que é outra biblioteca.

2 Opções

#### noConflict();

No jquery voce o padrao é acessar ele pela variavel `$` mas exatamente para evitar conflito com outras bibliotecas ele tem o metodo `noConflict()`que "redireciona" o jquery para a sua variavel, ex:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq('#meuid').fadeIn();
```

#### Ordem do carregamento

Talvez consiga resolver o conflito somente carregando o jquery antes do prototype.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/prototype.forms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Observação: esta dando erro 404 nessa url http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php

Editado.

#### Solução

Acho que encontrei o problema real.
O erro que me referi anteriormente foi esse "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

No seu codigo ja tem isso: `var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()` então basicamente a variavel `$`não existe, dai o erro. seu codigo deve ser algo desse tipo:

```
function confirmar() {
    $JQuery( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Excluir pedido": function() {
          $JQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
          funcao_b();
        },
        'Cancelar': function() {
          $JQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
          console.log('cancelado');
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Apenas troquei todos os `$`por `$JQuery`.